# Correct Concurrent Collection for storing timed non-recurring structures

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, collections, concurrency

I am searching for right thread-safe collection (concurrent collection) for the following scenario:

I may have requests from an external source which generates GUIDs (so it is unique and non-recurring). I need to store (say the last 100 requests) and check if duplicate GUIDs are delivered or not. I may not save all GUIDs more than 100 or so due to some limitations.

Now the problem is that when this mechanism is used in a service, it must be bound to 100 items and searching based on GUIDs is vital.

I decided to use `ConcurrentDictionary` yet I doubt it is a good decision since I may change the keys after using the whole 100 slots. I may find a good mechanism to replace the oldest requests when dictionary is full.

Any idea is much appreciated.

A code snippet is provided to show my incomplete implementation

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, TimedProto> IncidentsCreated = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TimedProto>(20, 100);

    private static bool AddTo_AddedIncidents(proto ReceivedIncident)
    {
        try
        {
            int OldestCounter = 0;
            DateTime OldestTime = DateTime.Now;

            if (IncidentsCreated.Count < 100)
            {
                TimedProto tp = new TimedProto();
                tp.IncidentProto = ReceivedIncident;
                tp.time = DateTime.Now;
                IncidentsCreated.AddOrUpdate(ReceivedIncident.IncidentGUID,  tp,
                    (s,i) => i);
                return true;
            }
            else //array is full, a replace oldest mechanism is required
            {

            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogEvent("AddTo_AddedIncidents\n"+ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            return false;
        }
    }


public struct proto
{
    public string IncidentGUID;
    //other variables
}

public struct TimedProto
{
    public proto IncidentProto;
    public DateTime time;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen when the queue is full? Throw away the new items? Or throw away the oldest items? Or block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: http://ayende.com/blog/162529/trivial-lru-cache-impl?key=02e8069c-62f8-4042-a7d2-d93806369824&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AyendeRahien+%28Ayende+%40+Rahien%29

Your implementation is flawed since you do use DateTime which has a granularity of 15ms. This means that you can accidentally delete even your most recent guids if you have a high inflow.

```
public class LruCache<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly int _capacity;
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    class Reference<T> where T : struct
    {
   public T Value;
    }

    private class Node
    {
        public TValue Value;
        public volatile Reference<long> Ticks;
    }

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Node> _nodes = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Node>();

    public LruCache(int capacity)
    {
        Debug.Assert(capacity > 10);
        _capacity = capacity;
    }

    public void Set(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        var node = new Node
        {
            Value = value,
            Ticks = new Reference<long> { Value = _stopwatch.ElapsedTicks }
        };

        _nodes.AddOrUpdate(key, node, (_, __) => node);
        if (_nodes.Count > _capacity)
        {
            foreach (var source in _nodes.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Ticks).Take(_nodes.Count / 10))
            {
                Node _;
                _nodes.TryRemove(source.Key, out _);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool TryGet(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        Node node;
        if (_nodes.TryGetValue(key, out node))
        {
            node.Ticks = new Reference<long> {Value = _stopwatch.ElapsedTicks};
            value = node.Value;
            return true;
        }

        value = default(TValue);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, yet since in the rush hours, I think there wouldn't be 100 requests even per minute! My main problem is with re-keying the dictionary which is time consuming. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: If there are not many requests then you cannot have a perf problem with only 100 elements in your dictionary. Please measure before going straight to conclusions. Either your inflow is much higher or you have a perf bottleneck elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Circular Buffer for this - there are plenty of implementations around, including [this one](http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com/), and making a thread-safe wrapper for one of them wouldn't be hard.

With only 100 or so slots, looking up by key would be reasonably efficient, and inserting would be extremely efficient (no reallocation as old items are discarded and replaced by new ones).

Comment: why circular buffer? Is there any thing useful in circular buffer for the situation? Can't get the point here :)

Comment: With a circular buffer your items will be added in chronological order, and once the capacity is reached, the oldest will be automatically replaced as new items are added.